# Restore whatsapp files from old phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

A friend of mine recently switched phones because the old one was sent to repair a broken screen.

After the switch, she noticed that some messages that were important had not been transfered. So far, I think that as she had no wifi at home, the backup was old and not updated.

Since she still has the old phone, is there a way to retrieve the old messages and add to the backup? I fear that if she just switches terminal again Whatsapp will just erase those old messages with the most recent of the backup.

Is there any way to access those messages? Ideally, adding them to the messages in the current phone, although if we just can access them it would be enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot restore WhatsApp backup without Google Services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231731/cannot-restore-whatsapp-backup-without-google-services)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whatsapp Chat Backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242261/whatsapp-chat-backup)

Comment: @alecxs thanks for the links. The issue is that since she has been using the new phone for a while, maybe there was a way to combine the old backup from the old phone with the messages in the new phone, but the more I research the more unlikely it is. For the time being I will work on getting a copy of the files on CD and try to read the DB. In any case if I will find anything interesting I will try to answer this myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying WhatsApp chat history to new Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241431/copying-whatsapp-chat-history-to-new-android)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/search/member?user_id=5008416